# for loops, numpy and sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, numpy, for-loop

I want to run code in a loop n times where n is the number of items that I've selected in SQLite.

```
import numpy as np
items=c.execute(
    "SELECT COUNT() from statements  WHERE [Col1] LIKE ? || '%' "
    "AND [Col2] = ? AND [Type] = 'type_1'",
    (Col1, Col2,))
n=c.fetchall()#the way i am getting n produces a tuple

for i in np.arange(0,n[0]):
      #run some code
```

[where c is a cursor]

The above produces an error when the loop starts:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: arange: scalar arguments expected instead of a tuple.
```

I think thats because its grabbing the tupple not the intiger from the tupple.
I normally code in matlab so what i wanted to produce was something like

```
for i =1:n
     #run some code
```

but couldn't find a python equivalent. Also the way I am using sqlite is probably clumsy.

Comment: MySQL or SQLite ?

Comment: `fetchall()` returns a _list_ of rows that match the query.  If you expect it to only produce one row, it's simpler to use `fetchone()` instead.

Comment: If you want a loop to run `N` times, use `for i in range(N):`

Comment: SQLite, its now corrected above

Comment: Just use `for i in items`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
items=c.execute(
    "SELECT COUNT() from statements  WHERE [Col1] LIKE ? || '%' "
    "AND [Col2] = ? AND [Type] = 'type_1'",
    (Col1, Col2,))
n=c.fetchall()#the way i am getting n produces a tuple

for i in np.arange(0,n[0]):
      #run some code
```